# What are these various settings in Charles proxy?

Tags: charles-proxy

[Screenshot of **Charles proxy throttle** setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzQYl.png)

Can anyone describe them in layman terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used this option in Charles Proxy, but I did on Chrome.
"Throttling" has to do with regulating network speed, so by this feature you can simulate poorer connection speed, as if connecting with 2G, 3G or so.
This is useful to detect problems that only arise when timeouts occur, for example.
(please note that, obviously, you will not be able to simulate higher speeds than the one provided by your ISP)